# Community promotion ads

Tags: support, status-completed, site-promotion

This is in relation to [this post by Robert Cartaino](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/community-promotion-ads/). We'd like to request a meta post on community promotion ads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's now up at [Community Promotion Ads - 2H 2011](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1157/community-promotion-ads-2h-2011). Enjoy!