# Community Promotion Ads - 2H 2011

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, community-ads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Community Promotion Ads - 1H 2012](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1448/community-promotion-ads-1h-2012)

#### What in the Wide, Wide World of Sports is Going On Here?

TL;DR -- put images and links in the answers. If they get voted up enough, they will appear on the main site as community promotion ads.

#### But whyyyyyyy?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- cool site-related open source apps
- the site's twitter account
- scripts packs or power tools
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. And to click on it for great justice!

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently 6) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/1157).

Comment: "cool apple related open source apps"??

Comment: How to remove ads that are only valid up to a certain point in time, say event promotion?

Answer (score 14):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Answer (score 7):

[image: Theory of Computing Blog Aggregator]

Comment: I thought it might be worthwhile to point visitors there. I am open to suggestions regarding the image.

Comment: How about inserting the two-state automaton logo in the middle ?

Comment: You mean the one from the cstheory.se logo? I do not think this is appropriate as the blog aggregator is a separate thing. Does it have a logo I missed?

Comment: oh never mind. I was confused.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Submit your papers for SODA 2012 !]

Comment: How will event ads be treated once the events are over? Are you going to delete this answer?

Comment: I don't know. As for this particular event, it never crossed the 6 vote threshold, so I don't think it ever made it as an ad

Comment: Then think again, because I will upvote if(f) there is a well-defined garbage collection process. ;)

Comment: I don't have control over how the ads are processed: You should probably ask @Dori

Answer (score 1):

[image: Citations of cstheory.SE]

Comment: I am not quite satisfied with the formulation. Suggestions? Also, the graph looks a bit clunky because I gimped it out of our header image. Does somebody still have the original sources?

Comment: Maybe @Jin might have it

Comment: I like the idea, but it is very unclear where this image actually links to because the image does not tell anything about it and the URL is that of a URL shortener.

Comment: I agree. I am open to suggestions; how do you visualise the concept of citations? Btw, I normally dislike URL shorteners, too, but in this case the original URL is not descriptive either. I can recommend longurlplease.com

Comment: I like [that one from tex.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/community-promotion-ads-1h-2011/1504#1504). I might try something in this direction: "from answers to papers -- publications citing the answers given here." What do you think?