# Community Promotion Ads - 2012

Tags: discussion, community-ads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Community Promotion Ads - 2013](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1619/community-promotion-ads-2013)

We're hitting the start of the new year, and that means a new iteration of the Community Promotion Ads!

#### What in the Wide, Wide World of Sports is Going On Here?

TL;DR -- put images and links in the answers. If they get voted up enough, they will appear on the main site as community promotion ads.

#### But whyyyyyyy?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- cool site-related open source apps
- the site's twitter account
- scripts packs or power tools
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. And to click on it for great justice!

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently 6) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/1448).

Comment: Is it legitimate to just copy-paste from last year?

Comment: @Raphael Aside from the sample twitter ad that I'm about to post, in general, a good idea would be to put a fresh new face on any ads that you'd like to repost. Part of the reason of having a cycle is to avoid staleness in ads - both in cropping out the ads that no one follows anymore (but which aren't going to get downvoted) and to allow for a new spin on recycled ads.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Comment: I think this needs a better image in the center.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Mathematica at StackExchange -- Help this community grow!]

Comment: [Mathematica.SE](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) is a new StackExchange site for questions about [Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/). The site is still in beta and needs to grow before it can graduate.  While I am not active here, I think there might be an overlap between this site's visitors and our potential audience.