# Community Promotion Ads - 2013

Tags: discussion, community-ads

As it is December 2012, we are now going to reset our Community Promotion Ads for the new year.

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- cool site-related open source apps
- the site's twitter account
- script packs or power tools
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/1619).

Comment: TCS.se — plz upvote this question to help with site promotion. to help with site promotion, am thinking of building icons for [a] google+ TCS community, [b] the TCS feed aggregator, [c] TCS.se blog page (unfortunately currently not updated).... etc... any other ideas? am thinking of building them if this question gets upvoted to more than 6. icons have to be upvoted to at least 6 to meet the threshhold. does anyone know if they are used anywhere but tcs.se, or can they show up on other sites? found a cool free image/photo of alan turing/enigma statue as a start...

Comment: wondering. does this mechanism not apply to beta sites? think it would be helpful to plug it into [cs.se](http://cs.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 8):

[image: Join Crypto Stackexchange]

Answer (score 7):

[image: writeLaTeX - Real Time Collaborative Mathematical Programming in your Browser]

Comment: This is an ad from TeX SX, which may also be useful here - firstly, you can easily use it to collaborate & iterate to reach answers in math & CS (not just in TeX), and secondly, it is a great option for working through mathematical problems on an iPad or other tablet (for which there are limited alternatives). Happy to let the community vote decide - I'm one of the developers of writeLaTeX, so any feedback appreciated, thanks.

Comment: hi john, interesting. is there an "export to url image" or "export to image" feature? that would be neat for chat rooms on stackexchange which currently do not support latex fmtting but can inline hosted images. if it exported to the stackexchange image hosting, that would be cool too

Comment: @vzn That's a great idea - we'd had similar thoughts about a "post to forum" option, but this is a neat way of doing it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Just a quick update -- you can now share Read-only links to documents on writelatex -- so if you create an example with code you want to share, you can do it via the read only link. Here's an example showing how to include an image in a header: https://www.writelatex.com/read/ptthjxswfnnc

Answer (score 5):

[image: Academia Stack Exchange]

Comment: uh, nice icon, where did you get it? did you make it? but... huh? the idea is that it would be for _TCS.se!_ right? ... any ideas there? why did you post an ad for a different stackexchange?

Comment: @vzn: Hum, the way I understood it is that if we get enough upvotes, then there will an ad for AC.SE on TCS.SE (thus attracting cool people to our site! ;)). It comes from there: http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/332/community-ads-for-2013

Comment: "our site"? this site you posted your answer on is meta. _cstheory_ .stackexchange.com....?

Comment: @vzn: Sorry, by "our site", I meant Academia.SE. Yes, I do realise this is cstheory, and I would like to have an Ad for Ac.SE on CSTheory.SE.

Comment: ok thx for the link it helps to explain the sort of "crossposting" mechanism, see it is tricky because the members of one group have to vote for ads from another group for it to actually get approved! kinda funky.... however there does seem to be some other mechanism in stackexchange where they rotate ads for other groups on different groups on the main page banner. so there may be a small chance that academia banner ads will appear occasionally on tcs.se anyway....

Answer (score 4):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting. Last time it was noted that the image could use some fixin'.

Comment: this is totally reasonable & suggest the TCS.se audience/"community" attempt to transcend the current/apparent long period of _resistance, lethargy & near-neglect_ over site promotion & upvote it just to get a single icon through the approval process & see it work, get further attn/interest in icons & site promotion, etc... _can anyone out there actually muster a click on the upvote button?_

Answer (score 2):

[image: What's going on? Help us find out!]